# Change BottomNavigationView with a button inside a RecyclerView Item

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, maps, bottomnavigationview

The application has a BottomNavigationView for navigating between fragments. One of the Fragments related to the BottomNavigationView has a Fragment as a child containing a RecyclerView and each RecyclerView Item has a Button attached to it.

[image]

I would need to navigate the BottomNavigationView to another Fragment with an OnClick of the Button (Highlighted with the red) inside the RecyclerView Item. I have tried different ways but I have not gotten it to work so far.
The Click is handled inside the Adapter of the RecyclerView. (The code inside the OnClickListener is just to clarify what I am trying to do.)

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull LocationsViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ...

        holder.showMarkerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            
              BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView)v.findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
                navigation.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_map);

                    }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is created an interface implemented by your **Activity**

First create an interface that i called `OnItemClick` :

```
public interface OnItemClick{

    void onItemClick();
}
```

Following on your activity implement this interface like below :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnItemClick{

    /*
        rest of your code
    */

    @Override
    public void onItemClick() {
        navigation.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_map);
    }
}
```

On your Fragment you need to pass the Activity into your Adapter

```
YourAdapter adapter = new YourAdapter(requireActivity());
```

And on your adapter you need to initialize the interface like below :

```
 OnItemClick listener;

 public YourAdapter(Activity activity) {
        listener= ((MainActivity) activity);
    }
```

And finaly to call the method on your activity just call it like below

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull LocationsViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ...

        holder.showMarkerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                     listener.onItemClick();

                 }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped with understanding the concept of interfaces a little better. If I may ask as an extra, then how could I include data from the RecyclerView Item to the Fragment that is opened with the onItemClick(). Basically the button that is clicked navigates to a Map Fragment and I would need to pass a LatLng of the clicked item to the MapFragment. Can an interface be used for passing values or i would have to use Intents and Bundles?

Comment: you can change the signature of the interface method to `onItemClick (Location LatLng)` in this case you can pass LatLng to you activity afterwards you just have to send this LatLng to your map fragment. there is a lot of communication method between activity and Fragment like ViewModel , Bundel

Comment: what method you use to switch between your shards. `replace ()` or `show ()` and `hide ()`?

Comment: The MainActivity uses NavController to navigate between fragments, I used the ```.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_map);```  for the button.
I changed the onItemClick() to onItemClick(LatLng latLng) to get the latlng from the RecyclerView item to the MainActivity. Now I made a new interface to get the LatLng to the MapFragment from the MainActivity but it returns null. 

` @Override
    public void onItemClick(LatLng latLng) {
        navView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_map);
        locationToMap.locationToMap(latLng); `

Comment: If I understood correctly you created an interface to send the locations from your activity to your map frageme

Comment: Yes, but it did not work. I made a new question for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67083340/passing-value-from-adapter-to-fragment