# Passing value from Adapter to a BottomNavigationView Fragment in Navigation components

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, bundle

The application has a `BottomNavigationView` on the `MainActivity` which deals with the navigation between Fragments. One of the Fragments has a `RecyclerView` in it and the items of the `RecyclerView` have a button.

I am trying to make the `RecyclerView` Items' button navigate to another Fragment and pass a value along with it but I keep receiving a null object reference with passing the data.

1. I created an interface to get the click to the `MainActivity` for the Fragment switch and created a Bundle to communicate the received value to the required Fragment

```
// The interface
public interface OnItemClickListener {

    void onItemClick();
```

The Adapter class

```
//Define interface
 OnItemClickListener listener;

//Create constructor for interface
    public LocationsAdapter(Activity activity) {
        listener = (MainActivity)activity;

...
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull LocationsViewHolder holder, int position) {

//A click listener for the button
        holder.showMarkerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
//Create instance of MapFragment to pass data as Bundle
                MapFragment mapFragment = new MapFragment();
 LatLng latLng = new LatLng(markerObject.getLatitude(),markerObject.getLongitude());
//Create Bundle and add data
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("latitude",markerObject.getLatitude().toString());
bundle.putString("longitude",markerObject.getLongitude().toString());
                listener.onItemClick(bundle);
                    }
        });
}
```

2. Then in the MainActivity I implemented the interface to switch the View of the BottomNavigation.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnItemClickListener {
    BottomNavigationView navView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                 R.id.navigation_home,R.id.navigation_map, R.id.navigation_locations, R.id.navigation_profile)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick() {
        navView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_map);
    }
}
```

3. As a final step I called on the Bundle I made in the first step but that's where the null object reference comes up.

```
//MapFragment
private void setCam(){
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        if (getArguments() != null ){
            String SLatitude = bundle.getString("latitude");
            String SLongitude = bundle.getString("longitude");
            Double latitude = Double.parseDouble(SLatitude);
            Double longitude = Double.parseDouble(SLongitude);
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 20));
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), latLng.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "error present", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you include the code where you setup the fragment in your main activity?

Comment: You are creating the bundle and putting data in it but not passing it anywhere. Track down what happens to the `mapFragment` object that you created.

Comment: @ShayKin I added the full MainActivity

Comment: @M.Azyoksul Yes, now I understand the problem, the Bundle has to be commited to the fragment I will switch to for the fragment to have access to the Bundle. How do I reference the same instance of the MapFragment that the BottomNavigation is using? I understand that usually a Bundle is commited with a FragmentManager, like ```getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, fragment).commit(); ``` but since the navigation is taken care of by NavController then I can't use a FragmentManager.

Comment: Why not using a [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate#host-activity) in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MapFragment mapFragment = new MapFragment();
LatLng latLng = new LatLng(markerObject.getLatitude(),markerObject.getLongitude());
//Create Bundle and add data
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("position",latLng.toString());
mapFragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

Here the `mapFragment` is just a created object that is not used in the navigation graph. i.e. it's a standalone object that is independent of the navigation, so it is not involved in the navigation as it's not the same as the current `mapFragment` fragment in the navGraph.

**Solution:**

In order to solve this, you need to pass the argument whenever you switch among fragments of the BottomNavigationView, and registering `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` is a good place for that:

First allow the adapter to send the arguments back to the activity through the listener callback

So, modify the listener callback to accept a parameter

```
interface OnItemClickListener listener {
    void onItemClick(Bundle args);
}
```

Apply that on adapter

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull LocationsViewHolder holder, int position) {

        //A click listener for the button
        holder.showMarkerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(markerObject.getLatitude(),markerObject.getLongitude());
                
                //Create Bundle and add data
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("position",latLng.toString());
                
                //Interface to transport the click event to the MainActivity to switch Fragment in the BottomNavigationView
                listener.onItemClick(bundle);
            }
        });
}
```

And finally, register  `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` to the `navView` and modify the callback to accept the Bundle in activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnItemClickListener {
    BottomNavigationView navView;
    
    private Bundle mapArgs;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                 R.id.navigation_home,R.id.navigation_map, R.id.navigation_locations, R.id.navigation_profile)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);
        
        
        navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                navController.navigate(item.getItemId(), mapArgs);
                return true;
            }
        });     
        
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(Bundle args) {
        navView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_map);
        mapArgs = args;
    }


}
```

Comment: Thank you, I got it working but I have one more question. I updated the MapFragment method in the question for a better understanding. If I push the button inside the RecyclerView's Item, it navigates to the MapFragment but the getArguments() method returns null, though if I go back to the RecyclerView and push the button again, then it opens the MapFragment and shows the Toast with the LatLng but it does not move the camera. The setCam method is called inside the onMapReady().

Comment: Hi @EdwardAarma I see that `listener.onItemClick();` still get called after  `listener.onItemClick(bundle);` Can you please check if it's still there; if yes then remove it

Comment: That was my bad, didn't notice leaving that in the question, i fixed it now, but otherwise I only have onItemClick with the bundle included.

Comment: @EdwardAarma Do you still have issues?

Comment: Yes, basically the bundle returns null the first time I navigate from the RecyclerView to the MapFragment with the button, if I recreate the MapFragment, then I get the Bundle but the moveCamera(); method does not work.

Comment: As `getArguments` returned `null`, without debugging there are a couple of reasons, first that the adapter returns a null bundle; the second is that the activity local `Bundle` object can be set to null in configuration change.. If you're using a `ViewModel`, you can save the returned bundle in it instead of doing `mapArgs = args` within `onItemClick()`

Answer (score 1):

When using the navigation controller, you pass in data with parameters. Go to your navigation component XML file and make the following changes;

1.Inside the navigation action, you need to add an argument.

```
<action
    android:id="@+id/action_id"
    app:destination="@id/destinationFragment">
    <argument
        android:name="paramterName"
        app:argType="string" />
</action>
```

2.Add the same argument to the destination fragment

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/coursesNavFragment"
    android:name="com.example.example.DestinationFragment"
    android:label="destination_fragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/destination_fragment" >
    <argument
        android:name="parameterName"
        app:argType="string" />
</fragment>
```

You can easily do this using the design view as well.

Now the function you call to navigate to the destination fragment expects you to pass it a parameter.

```
navigationController.navigate(actionSourceFragmentToDestinationFragment("text123"))
```

Then you can extract the bundle in the destination fragment.

```
val parameter = DestinationFragmentArgs.fromBundle(requireArguments()).parameterName
// parameter has the value of "text123"
```

Since the navigation component uses safeargs, you can pass any type of parameter that inherits from [Parcellable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable).